# Question about approximate squaring iteration

Tags: iteration

the iteration map $x*\left\lceil x \right\rceil$, where the initial term is a non integer rational number $b/a$ with $b>a$ and $a>1$. the growth rate of this iteration is similar to the growth rate of Fermat numbers(!). If the initial term is (for example) $200/199$, then how we know that after $1000$ steps the number becomes an integer or not ? Because the number at $1000$ steps is very very HUGE number(!). I tried residues method, but that didn't work at all !. Is there a simple method to check this out ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, so again, this site is about specific problems with Wolfram Mathematica. Is your question about problem in implementation of an algorithm in Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Yes sth like that..

Comment: Then I am afraid you need to do some research in how to approach this problem and if you get stuck implementing it, let us know where exactly is the problem.

Comment: I mean Is there an algorithm that actually can handle this easily ?

Comment: Please add code for what you've already tried (residues method?) to your question.

Comment: A simple, and extremely naive Mathematica implementation is `iterate[x_] := x Ceiling[x]; Nest[iterate, 200/199, 1000]`.  But it takes a long time to run.

Comment: @Brandon, Please use the edit option to place the `iterate...` example in the actual post. As it is, I almost missed seeing the one in the comments, and nearly voted to close based on lack of any concrete example.

Comment: This link maybe the solution (at page $20$) $$\href{neilsloane.com/doc/apsq.pdf}$$